# KSH Setting alias name with argument in alias name

Tags: cron, alias, ksh

I work in a multi user environment where multiple users can (and often do) edit the crontab simultaneously.  This can sometimes lead to issues where some users' changes aren't appearing in the crontab as another user had made changes a few seconds afterward (to an older copy of the cron).

As a quick hack, I wanted to keep a history of crontabs - running a diff on these would show us immediately where alterations should have been made should there be anyone working on the crontab simultaneously.

I created a very basic script:

```
#! /bin/ksh

export datetime=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`
echo "Your username?: \c"
read username
crontab -l > /u01/app/oracle/dba/scripts/audit/cron_hist/"crontab_"$username"_"$datetime

export cronfile=/u01/app/oracle/dba/scripts/audit/cron_hist/"crontab_"$username"_"$datetime
### echo $cronfile
vi $cronfile

crontab < $cronfile
```

My intention was to have to script run everytime a user types "crontab -e" on the command line.

I wanted to set an alias to use "crontab -e" and execute the script.  However, I've realised I cant use alias with a command with an argument in it as the alias name.

Is there a way around this?  I only ever want my program to run if "crontab -e" is specifically called.

NOTE:  All users login to the same user environment (i.e. admin), so they're all editting the same crontab.

Comment: you can remove the alias in your script. Is it unalias in ksh? not sure.

Comment: Jean-François Fabre - there's no alias in my script.  What I'd like to do is setrthis script as an alias using the alias name "crontab -e".  Obviosuly I could set the alias as "crontab" but that isn't ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a function called exactly like `crontab` command which checks if first argument is `-e`.

(somewhere in your `.kshrc` file)

```
function crontab
{
  if [ "$1" = "-e" ] ; then
     # call my script
     echo callscript first
  fi
  # call crontab in a subprocess
  ksh crontab $*
  # or maybe call with full path /sbin/crontab $*
}
```

Note: the last line `ksh crontab $*` is not optimal but I don't remember or find a way to call the real command. With aliases you just backslash the command (`\crontab`) but with functions it doesn't work hence the final workaround.

Comment: Works a treat!  Thanks.   I modified it slightly to use an else otherwise it still runs crontab -e after the initial script is run.

Comment: I'm relieved, since I only tested that with MSYS bash. But I have a lot of xp in old HP ksh scripts from last century :) That's also when I learned that aliases cannot take parameters, functions can.